# How to filter out records in a Case Statement using Min(date) in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I am working with a table similar to one below- 
**ID    Type    Size    Date**    

1   new 10  1/30/2020 17:16 
1   new 10  1/30/2020 17:25 
3   old 15  1/30/2020 5:50  
4   unused  20  1/30/2020 5:30  
6   used    25  1/29/2020 18:30

I need my output to look like this-
**ID    Type    Size    Date Category**   

1   new 10  1/30/2020 17:16 A
1   new 10  1/30/2020 17:25 other
3   old 15  1/30/2020 5:50  B
4   unused  20  1/30/2020 5:30  C
6   used    25  1/29/2020 18:30 other

The condition for Category A needs to take in the first occurrence of the record. I am trying to do the following but it doesn't work well since min(date) gives an error-

```
select *,
case when type = 'new' and Size = '10' and min(date) then 'A'`
when type = 'old' and Size = '15' then 'B'
when type = 'unused' and Size = '20' then 'C'
else 'other'
end as category
from table1
```

Is there a workaround here without using a window function? (the table size is extremely large)

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? These actually are two different products, please tag only the relevant one.

Comment: case **expression** , please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case 
        when type = 'new' and Size = '10' 
            and row_number() over(partition by type, size, order by date) = 1
            then 'A'`
        when type = 'old' and Size = '15' then 'B'
        when type = 'unused' and Size = '20' then 'C'
        else 'other'
    end as category
from table1
```

Comment: thank you- this works only if the date column has 2 distinct entries. in cases when the timestamp is the same, i would still want the first occurring entry

Comment: @Nimmi: `row_number()` guarantees that each number is assigned just once, so only one row will be ranked `1`.  But maybe you want `order by date, id`?